# enum values() - call each time or assign to variable

Tags: java, enums

From reading the [Enum Types, The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/):

> The compiler automatically adds some special methods when it creates
>   an enum. For example, they have a static values method that returns an
>   array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are
>   declared. This method is commonly used in combination with the
>   for-each construct to iterate over the values of an enum type.

I'd like to know what exactly the `values()` method does. Is it effectively just returning a class member / constant, or is it more going on under the hood? The following code is *in no way* meant to demonstrate best practise but highlights how the answer this question would affect how I might approach a problem:

If `values()` returns a class member / constant I would consider calling it liberally (see `getAllValues()`), like this:

```
enum ExampleEnum {
    A("A's String"), B("B's String"), C("C's String");
    ExampleEnum(String someValue) {
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

    private final String someValue;

    private String[] getAllValues() {
        String[] result = new String[values().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < values().length; i++) {
            result[i] = values()[i].someValue;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

If however it was doing actual work, I'd change `getAllValues()` as follows:

```
private String[] getAllValues() {
    ExampleEnum[] values = values();
    String[] result = new String[values.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        result[i] = values[i].someValue;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you call `values()` you are creating new array filled with enum constants. You can easy test it with `==` operator

```
System.out.println(ExampleEnum.values()==ExampleEnum.values());//prints false
```

So second option would be better because it creates this array once. But to improve it you could simply store result of `values()` outside of this method and reuse it when need. This way you would simply invoke it once. You can also create collection of `someValue` elements earlier, store it as unmodifiable collection (like List) and return it.

So your code could look like:

```
enum ExampleEnum {
    A("A's String"), B("B's String"), C("C's String");
    ExampleEnum(String someValue) {
        this.someValue = someValue;
    }

    private final String someValue;

    private static final ExampleEnum[] vals = values();
    private static final List<String> names = Collections.unmodifiableList(
            Stream.of(vals).map(en -> en.someValue).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    public static List<String> getAllValues() {
        return names;
    }
}
```